# UIScrollView scrollViewBeginDecelerating not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

In my scrollview, I have successfully used scrollViewDidEndDecelerating in my App.  However, I'm adding a video player and would like to have it loaded prior to the scroll taking place.  I located the delegate method scrollViewBeginDecelerating in Apple's docs, but it doesn't get called.  Here is the code:

```
 #pragma mark - UIScrollView Delegate

 - (void)scrollViewBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender
 {
 // setup movie view
 }

 - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender
 {
 // previously used to display header text, etc
 }
```

Comment: did you set delegate as scrollview.delegate=self;

Comment: The delegate might not receive this message until dragging has occurred over a small distance.

Comment: The scroll view’s dragging property is set to YES, and its delegate is sent the scrollViewWillBeginDragging: message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` and `scrollViewDidScroll:`. These will give you information when the user starts scrolling. Deceleration delegate calls will only start, once the user has lifted his or her finger, and there is still inertia.

Comment: I added scrollViewDidScroll and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The methods declared by the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol allow the adopting delegate to respond to messages from the `UIScrollView` class and thus respond to, and in some affect, operations such as scrolling, zooming, deceleration of scrolled content, and scrolling animations.

The scroll view’s dragging property is set to YES, and its delegate is sent the `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` message

[image]

**The Complete Delegate Message Sequence**

When the user touches the screen the tracking sequence begins. The tracking property is set to YES immediately, and remains YES as long as the user’s finger is in contact with the screen, regardless of whether they are moving their finger.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollingViewContent/ScrollingViewContent.html